# SSRS 2008 - The stream cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We are using SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 to build reports. We're accessing the reports trough the Webservice (ReportExecution2005.asmx), render them to html to embed them in an aspx page. Everything works quite well.

Only on the computer of one developer images aren't rendering. When copying the url of the image and pasting it in the browser, it says:

Reporting Services Error

The stream cannot be found. The stream identifier that is provided to an operation cannot be located in the report server database. (rsStreamNotFound)

The guy is running Windows Vista, on my own Windows 7 environment everything works. With SSRS 2005 I had the same problem on Windows 7, but it was resolved by installing SSRS 2008.

Any ideas?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502186/embedded-images-in-ssrs-reports-not-displaying-permissions-issue

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient question but I stumbled across the following article which describes (in great detail) what a particular development group found during their research.

[Avoiding Reporting Services ‘StreamNotFound’ Exception when Viewing Multiple Instances of the Same Report](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2009/03/avoiding-reporting-services.html)

**In the end, here is what solved their problem:**

"... [we] discovered you can disable session cookies (in the ReportServer.dbo.ConfigurationInfo table) which (after an IISReset) indeed fixed the problem entirely."